Amazon Connect Email addresses
My problem is right now i have an inbound voice and chat flows on my Amazon connect.
The problem is that i want to create an email diagram flow that will be connected to the voice and chat flow so when the customer call and give the inputs from the intents of amazonlex that i have created, to collect those datas and send them with notification to some seperates agents with emails.
I wanted to use sns i also have created lambda function but i dont know how to connect those diagrams if anyone can help that would be great!
Thank you in advance!
i tried everything but i dont know how to connect the right diagram flow for the email and how to connect it on voice and chat inbound flows

Roughly, there are 3 steps involved:

Configure your Amazon Connect contact flow to interact with Amazon Lex, capturing customer intents and necessary information.

Use a Lambda function to send the collected customer information to SNS. The preferred option is to call the Lambda from Lex itself during the fulfillment phase; there is no need to call it from the flow. This ensures that the Lambda function is triggered as soon as Lex identifies the customer's intent and collects the required data. You can configure this in the Amazon Lex console under the "Fulfillment" section of the intent. Read more about it here.

Configure your SNS topic with the email addresses of the agents who need to receive these notifications.



Step 1 is done.
Step 2 is the problem because i have created an amazon lambda function but i dont know how to add parameters to it. and how to call it in the flow.
Step 3 is also done.
Do you know how can i call this lambda function in the flow and adding parameters to collect the data from the amazon lex?

I elaborated on this part - basically you configure Lex to call the lambda during the fulfillment phase. No need to call it from the contact-flow.
